# Plot multi characters stacked on over another in pinescript using plotchar

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am writing pinescript code where when one condition is true, either a shape or char is printed at bottom and when other condition is true another shape or char must be printed and these should be stacked and as of now these are overlapping each other.

Eg:

```
Condition 1: plotchar(show_comp_dot, char = "◙", location=location.bottom, color=comp_color, size=size.tiny)
Condition 2: plotchar(show_red_dot, char = "★", location=location.bottom, color=sq_color, size=size.tiny).
```

When at any candle these 2 are true, the chars should be stacked not overlapped and I am getting them overlapped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method explained [here](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-lift-plotshape-text-up).

Basically, you would use `\n` followed by a special non-printing character to lift the text.

```
//@version=4
study("Lift text", "", true)
// Use U+200E (Decimal 8206) as a non-printing space after the last "\n".
// The line will become difficult to edit in the editor, but the character will be there.
// You can use https://unicode-table.com/en/tools/generator/ to generate a copy/pastable character.
plotshape(true, "", shape.arrowup,      location.abovebar, color.new(color.white, 100), textcolor=color.green,     text="◙")
plotshape(true, "", shape.arrowup,      location.abovebar, color.new(color.white, 100), textcolor=color.lime,      text="★\n‎")
plotshape(true, "", shape.arrowdown,    location.belowbar, color.new(color.white, 100), textcolor=color.red,       text="◙")
plotshape(true, "", shape.arrowdown,    location.belowbar, color.new(color.white, 100), textcolor=color.maroon,    text="‎\n★")
```

[image]

Comment: When using the same for location.bottom with plotchar, it is displaying at the bottom for all the candles.

Comment: You cannot use `plotchar()`. It expects a char. You have more than one character in your string.